# Extending event definitions - Interface incorrectly implements interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, events, interface

I'm trying to enforce event definitions in my code using an interface and class of the same name as in the following example:

```
export declare interface ClientEvents {
    on(event: "event_name", data: (data: string) => void) : this;
    emit(event: "event_name", data: string) : boolean;
}

export class ClientEvents extends EventEmitter {}
```

This works well on its own for IDE completion and ensuring that only those events are broadcast by the event object.

The problem comes when I attempt to extend this interface, as below:

```
export declare interface SpecificClientEvents extends ClientEvents {
    on(event: "child_event_name", data: (data: string) => void) : this;
    emit(event: "child_event_name", data: string) : boolean;
}

export class SpecificClientEvents extends ClientEvents {}
```

I get the following errors:

`TS2430: Interface 'SpecificClientEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'ClientEvents'.` for the interface

`TS2415: Class 'SpecificClientEvents' incorrectly extends base class 'ClientEvents'.` for the class

I have also attempted to separate the class and interface into separate definitions as per the below example:

```
export interface ClientEventDefinitions {
    on(event: "event_name", data: (data: string) => void) : this;
    emit(event: "event_name", data: string) : boolean;
}

export class ClientEvents extends EventEmitter implements ClientEventDefinitions {}

export interface SpecificClientEventDefinitions {
    on(event: "child_event_name", data: (data: string) => void) : this;
    emit(event: "child_event_name", data: string) : boolean;
}

export class SpecificClientEvents extends ClientEvents implements SpecificClientEventDefinitions {}
```

This compiles OK but my IDE doesn't detect the event names like it does when the class and interface have the same name. Is this likely a problem with the IDE? This doesn't work for both the parent and child classes.

I'm also able to execute `new SpecificClientEvents().emit("an event that isn't defined");` without any errors using the 2nd example.

EDIT:

If I manually add the methods from the parent interface to the child interface, this works absolutely fine. But what's the point of extending the parent in the first place if I need to add the methods manually?

EDIT 2:

I opted to use the [strict event emitter package](https://github.com/bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types) with the following code to meet my needs

```
export type ClientEventEmitter = StrictEventEmitter<EventEmitter, ClientEvents>;

export interface ClientEvents {
    event_name: (data: string) => void;
}

export type SpecificClientEventsEmitter = StrictEventEmitter<EventEmitter, SpecificClientEvents>;

export interface SpecificClientEvents extends ClientEvents {
    child_event_name: (data: string) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you may not be aware that you are using a feature called [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), which means your two interfaces have incompatible types and your first example has the expected behaviour.

Here is a simplified version for clarity:

```
interface A {
  prop: 'String literal type';
}

interface B extends A {
  prop: 'Another string literal type';
}
```

This will give you an error message saying: `Type '"Another string literal type"' is not assignable to type '"String literal type"'`

> I'm also able to execute new SpecificClientEvents().emit("an event
>   that isn't defined"); without any errors using the 2nd example.

This seems to be because `implements` is not enforcing the string literal type from `SpecificClientEventDefinitions` and the `SpecificClientEvents` class is instead using the types from `EventEmitter` (`string | symbol`).

Here is an alternative approach using a generic class which I think solves your problem:

```
export class ClientEvents<T extends string> extends EventEmitter {
  on(event: T, data: (data: string) => void): this {
    return super.on(event, data);
  }
  emit(event: T, data: string): boolean {
    return super.emit(event, data);
  }
}
```

With this code when you create a new emitter with `new ClientEvents<'special_event_name'>()`, the `on` and `emit` functions will require events with the `'special_event_name'` type.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378613/1832330) answer is best what you can get for your exact needs, but if you need a more complex mapping between event name and it's data type, you can use something like this

```
export interface ClientEvents<T> {
    on(event: keyof T, data: (d: T[typeof event]) => void) : this;
    emit(event: keyof T, data: T[typeof event]) : boolean;
}

type SpecificEvents = {
    eventName1: string,
    eventName2: number
}

class SpecificClientEvents implements ClientEvents<SpecificEvents> {
    on(event: keyof SpecificEvents, data: (d: SpecificEvents[typeof event]) => void) : this {
        switch (event) {
            case "eventName1":
                // compiler forces you to pass string
                data("string value");
                break;
            case "eventName2":
                // compiler forces you to pass number
                data(2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return this;
    }

    emit(event: keyof SpecificEvents, data: SpecificEvents[typeof event]): boolean {
        switch (event) {
            case "eventName1":
                // data is of type string
                break;
            case "eventName2":
                // data is of type number
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

or a simpler inline type where most IDE's will autocomplete implementation and correct argument types.

```
class SimpleEvents implements ClientEvents<{ eventName: number }> {
    on(event: "eventName", data: (d: number) => void): this {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    emit(event: "eventName", data: number): boolean {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=51&ssc=2&pln=43&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQBsFgUBRAN1JgGcAeAFQD44BvAKDi7giQApgVFAC44Aa2ABPCOjgMANHAAmmGJlF8lohgG0YksMBlxB1ALoBKOAF4WFCAiVXRMABYIaAbk7dgAWwQYASEYUQlpWQVlVXU5PQMjWVMUSzhRACMICEJgTCRvAF92dn1DOABlQ2wEdARsSmoaGzYfLmSYADlMP2AARlEaGChkAHN5VpMQrp6AJlEkAFc-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)